# Energy required moving a perfect sphere vs. wheel vs. cube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, gravity

Suppose I need to transport 1000 kg of water. I need to manually push the containers to move them along. How can I calculate the difference in energy it will take to do so, comparing these 3:

1) Perfect sphere (Capacity: 1000 kg of water)

2) Perfect wheel with a fixed width of 1 meter, and a diameter to accommodate 1000 kg of water

3) Perfect cube 1 meter on all sides (again, capacity: 1000 kg of water)

They all are dragged ("rolled" as in spheres and wheels) along the same surface type (say, pavement) and against the same **SLOPE**. Yes, we want to drag it up a ramp (say, 2:12 slope).

Comment: Moment of Inertia is what you should be looking for: [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mi.html)

Comment: @hardshit54 Could you please solve the example above. I am no expert at physics so I can't workout such complicated formulae. An example always helps.